# Wierd problem with dropdown in Jetpackcompose

Tags: padding

Im fairly new to Kotlin and jetpackcompose

I have a dropdown, but the thing is that, it is clickable on a large part of the screen, i can fix this the closer i put it to the top of the screen.

however this is a half baked solution, and im truly curious as to what im missing

this my code

i have a picture as well demonstrating the area of where i the dropdown is clickable, please note that the farther it is from the top, the larger the area gets. how can i define the "clickarea" so to speak.
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ckq0.png)

A little bonus, as u can see in the picture the, the actual list that gets shown is also a bit off the left, i seem to only be able to add some padding to listitems, not the list itself.

```
  override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(
                ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
            )
            setContent {
                Surface(color = Color("#FFE2E6F0".toColorInt())) {
                    OneDropdownsExample() //** the dropdown.**
                    VerifyEditDelete()


                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Composable **THE CODE FOR DROPDOWN**
    fun BTSSpinner(
        items: List<String>,
        selection: Int,
        onSelectionChangedCallback: (selection: Int) -> Unit,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        enabled: Boolean = true,
    ) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } // initial value

        Box {
            Column {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = items[selection],
                    onValueChange = { },
                    modifier = modifier
                        .padding(top = 50.dp)
                        .padding(start = 20.dp)
                        .height(50.dp),
                    trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Outlined.ArrowDropDown, null) },
                    readOnly = true,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color.White,
                        trailingIconColor = Color.Black,
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                        disabledBorderColor = Color.Transparent
                    ),

                    )
                DropdownMenu(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth(),
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                ) {
                    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .wrapContentWidth()
                                .height(50.dp),


                            onClick = {
                                onSelectionChangedCallback(index)
                                expanded = false
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = item,
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                color = Color(0xFF616265),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .wrapContentWidth()
                                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                            )
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .matchParentSize()
                    .background(Color.Transparent)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                    .clickable(
                        enabled = enabled,
                        onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
                    )
            )
        }
    }

**DEFINING THE CONTENT OF THE LIST. THIS IS WHAT IM CALLING IN THE ONCREATEVIEW**
    @Composable
    fun OneDropdownsExample() {
        var firstDropdownSelection by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }// starting pos

        val firstDropdownItems = listOf("Bitstation 1 ", "bitstation 2", "bitstation 3")
        Column {
            // First Dropdown
            BTSSpinner(
                items = firstDropdownItems,// vi passer vores liste til items.
                selection = firstDropdownSelection, // selection holder den nuværende valgte
                onSelectionChangedCallback = { selection -> // callback function
                    firstDropdownSelection = selection // selection holds the index of the new item.
                }
            )

            // Second Dropdown
        }
    }
```

Google, youtube, Stackoverflow